# django - Joining LogEntry to actual models

Tags: django, join, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

so i'm using the admin LogEntry object/table to log events in my app. I have a view where i'd like to display each LogEntry.
It would be really great if i could join the LogEntry with the actual objects they represent (so i can display attributes of the object inline with the log entry)
In theory this should be easy as we have the model type and id from the LogEntry but i can't figure out how to join them using a queryset.

i thought i could just grab all the ids of the different objects and make another dictionary for each object type and then join them somehow (maybe zip the lists together?) but that seems dumb and not very djano-ish/pythonic.

does anybody have better suggestions?

** **edit** **
just want to clarify am not looking to use admin, but roll a custom view and template.

Answer (score 2):

As I know Django uses [contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) to perform logging in admin. So you should create generic relation inside your model and then to show inlines in admin use  GenericTabularInline and GenericStackedInline. Please consult with the article.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import  GenericTabularInline
from django import forms
from some_app import models
from some_app.models import Item

class LogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LogEntry

class LogInline(GenericTabularInline):
    ct_field = 'content_type'
    ct_fk_field = 'object_id'
    model = LogEntry
    extra = 0

class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ItemForm
    inlines = [LogInline,]


admin.site.register(models.Item, ItemAdmin)
```

and you add to Item:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logs =  generic.GenericRelation(LogEntry)
```

this change won't create anything in your database, so there is no need to sync

Comment: cool. i've never used generic relations before. in my case then, do you recommend creating a generic relationship inside my model to the logEntry object?

Comment: ahh thanks for the code sample. makes things a lot clearer. a couple things. 
1st: I don't want to use the  admin. I want to roll my own view and template.
2nd: this way gives me a list of all items and then when looking at a paricular item, i see all the logs. I need it the other way around. I need a list of log entries and details on each item along the way. This is relevant because the query i execute is based on the LogEntries, not the items. thx!

Comment: Sorry, It seems like i forgot what you were asking and answered some other question. LogEntry has two fields "content_type", which connects to ContentType object, which has method get_object_for_this_type(*kwargs), you should call this method passing id = log_entry.object_id. This will give you your object. This is what GenericForeignKey do, but LogEntry doesn't have it, so you have to implement it yourself or set up your own logging (which is not hard).

Comment: thanks for your reply and apologies for delay in mine. I saw that function, but it seems kind of expensive because we would have to do a seperate database call for each object we return. I guess i'm off to implement my own logging....(or find someone smarter than me who has already done it and made it avail).

Answer (score 0):

Recent Django versions require to create a proxy for LogEntry:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import  GenericTabularInline

class LogEntryProxy(LogEntry):
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class LogInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = LogEntry
    extra = 0

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [LogInline,]

admin.site.register(models.Item, ItemAdmin)
```